# Read a plist from the document directory of the iPhone in a Unity3d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to read a `plist` file from document directory of an iPhone in Unity3D

Read image is sample but I have to read a plist

```
public static string GetiPhoneDocumentsPath ()
{
    string path = Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.Length - 5);
    path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('/'));
    return path + "/Documents";
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.unity.com/threads/read-write-plist-file-in-unity3d-iphone.110641/ It's a bit old, but maybe it could give you some guidelines.